# Vim adding junk to scripts

Tags: vimrc

### Information

**VIM version**

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 29 2020 00:47:39)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-2292
```

Operating System: Catalina 10.15.4

### What went wrong

I'm sure this will just be a configuration thing but I've been banging my head against the desk for hours trying to figure this out.

EDIT: Below I first noticed this happening on ALEFix - however I've realised even when I do :grep, `asofsdfas` is logged to the console... I'm going to keep digging.

If anyone knows a way to see what is being executed by vim that would be useful (ie show commands being run? - q: doesn't reveal anything)

---

When I run ALEFix on a python file it automatically inserts junk at the top:

```
asofsdfas
import logging
```

For me its always the same junk `asofsdfas` but if I keep saving it keeps inserting it.

Here is my ftplugin/python.vim

```
" Check Python files with flake8 and pylint.
let b:ale_linters = ['flake8', 'mypy']
" Fix Python files with autopep8 and yapf.
let b:ale_fixers = ['autopep8', 'yapf']

" python syntax
let g:python_highlight_all = 1
```

If I change to `let b:ale_fixers = []` it doesn't occur

If I pip uninstall autopep8 and yapf it doesn't occur

It still occurs if I have either only `let b:ale_fixers = ['autopep8']` or `let b:ale_fixers = ['yapf']`

Please someone help I'm losing my mind

EDIT:
Turns out it's also happening on my javascript fixers so isn't specific to this python stuff (but the same behaviour is occurring re: if I change the ale_fixers value)

Comment: Sounds like a temporary workaround is not to use ALEFix... odd bug though. (Aside) I’ve been happy with Black since I started using it to format python files on save (via ale). So happy, in fact, that I miss it in other languages.

Comment: Hi Phil, I would suggest making your vimrc file as small as possible and trying to reproduce this bug again. I've used `ALE` for a while and never had any trouble. Also, check which `autopep8` and `yapf`are used in ALE, try to run them manually. If you end up with no issue then it's probably something in your configuration and not in the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - have updated the question but essentially this is definitely not an ALE issue and something with my vimrc - am going to try to recreate a minimal example as @nobe4 suggested :+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem here was that I had

```
set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

in my vimrc

Removing this solved the issue.

I'm still not entirely sure *why*

EDIT: 
Oh my lord I've found it and it's colossally stupid. 
Thanks to @filbrandon:

> When you pass the shell a -i, it will read and execute your initialization file (such as .bashrc for bash.) If you're producing any output from that initialization file, that might explain it. If you run bash -ic 'echo hello' do you actually see anything other than "hello"?

Turns out I had `echo asofsdfas` in my `.bashrc`.... I'm using a mac so I only was ever checking my .bash_profile.

Thanks for taking this journey with me and apologies and thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you found the issue! But can you please expand on this a bit to make it a better answer? What was this line doing? Why did you have it there in the first place? Did you change it to something else or did you just remove it? Thanks!

Comment: Very good point - have updated that removing this line solved the issue. I wish I could elaborate more

Comment: When you pass the shell a `-i`, it will read and execute your initialization file (such as `.bashrc` for bash.) If you're producing any output from that initialization file, that might explain it. If you run `bash -ic 'echo hello'` do you actually see anything other than "hello"? Note that producing output from these initialization files is a problem for other commands as well, you should try to avoid that if possible. In any case, yeah the fix is good. (Do you happen to recall why you added this line in the first place?)

Comment: You are correct!  `bash -ic 'echo hello' also logs the `asofsdfas` junk I was getting before!
More digging from me to come